# Which image to use in community promotions ads of other Stack Exchange websites for TeX.SX?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I want to propose TeX.SX and promote it on the Academia.SX's [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/community-promotion-ads-2015) but I do not find any image to put in the advertisement. Is there any image for such purpose which is specifically designed for TeX.SX?

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][2]][3]
```

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: How about the logo of TeX.SX just above your post (main site, not this gray depressive logo ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good idea. I am also thinking of an image. People in chat are also discussing some points of view about such image.

Answer (score 11):

One of your users reached out to us over at GDSE in our chatroom. I have produced this for your community based on the graphics already used on your site.

[First Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gK3Q.png)

Updated with hyphen and attempted to justify as much as possible: [Second Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MNDa.png)

With the help of Paulo Cereda the final version looks like:

[image]

Come and check out [**GDSE**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) soon, we welcome typographical expertise with open arms. :)

Comment: As a user on TeX.SX, I have to thank you for your time. It is so nice.

Comment: can I suggest a small improvement? You could hyphenate `typeset-ting` and break it in two lines. It would make the line `related typeset-` not stand out, also, TeX is able to hyphenate without any problem, so why not show it? :)

Comment: @yo' great idea, I will do it by tonight at the latest.

Comment: It's very nice, thank you! `:)` I just feel the need of having `\TeX` and `\LaTeX` properly typeset (with the raising/lowering parts), but that's just me. Thank you again.

Comment: @PauloCereda I think it is better to change the phrase to `Q & A site for users of \TeX, \LaTeX and Friends.` with `\TeX` and `\LaTeX` as they appear in the output of TeX documents.

Comment: Also, I think that it would be better to put the phrase in the centre of the vertical space between bottom of the logo and bottom of the image. Currently, there is a large white space in the bottom of the image.

Comment: @PauloCereda and student I had a quick shot at kerning those logos in Photoshop, and unfortunately it will take more time than I can give to realise that. I do think it would be better, but it's beyond the scope of voluntary work. I can however change the phrase once, so I'll wait until later to see what your community decides. I do personally like that "*..and friends.*" more than the current ending, but it's not my site. Also, the idea of hyphenating the 'typesetting' would instead provide a simple yet perfectly relevant enhancement, that would not be possible with friends. Up to you guys.

Comment: Hyphenated nd justified i like it even more. But i bet not many will realize this as a real design feature for the logo *and* LaTeX.

Comment: I think it should be: "Q & A **site** for [...]"

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: the inclusion of *site* was causing a lot of trouble in the text flow, so Dom and I opted for the quickest and easiest solution. I tried hard to fit *site*, but all my tweaks resulted in a poor flow.